# Disable anspress users to answer a closed conversation in my website

Tags: wordpress, plugins

After the discussion is closed, how can I disable my website users to answer that closed discussion that is labeled as "closed" at my anspress plugin Q&A forum?

Is there anyway that you will help me out to change the code of anspress plugin such as follows?
http://snowykyoko.com/caselaw/legal-answers-2/question/186/howdy-titus-here/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if question has `closed` term using:

```
has_term( 'closed', 'question_label', get_question_id() )
```

**Code for version 1.4.3:**

Create a theme override by simply creating a new folder called `anspress` inside your active theme (not child theme). 
Now copy  `anspress/theme/default/answer-form.php` to your newly created folder.

Now paste this:

```
<?php
    $question_id =get_question_id() ;
    $current_user = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );
    $validate = ap_validate_form();
    if(!empty($validate['has_error'])){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" data-dismiss="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>'. __('Problem submitting form, please recheck form', 'ap') .'</div>';
    }
?>
<?php 
// make sure closed label slug is "closed"
if( ap_question_have_labels() && has_term( 'closed', 'question_label', get_question_id() ) ): ?>
    <div id="answer-form-c">        
        <div class="ap-avatar">
            <?php echo get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, ap_opt('avatar_size_qquestion') ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php ap_answer_form($question_id); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am still not be able to disable for my website users to answer their closed questions as followshttp://snowykyoko.com/caselaw/legal-answers-2/question/30/this-is-a-test/     Could you explain how to do it anyhow please?